# Node modules version conflict in angular

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I'm getting the following error when I try to run ***npm install***.

[image]

It works if I add the --force flag to the command, but I can't add it

Below are my dependencies. Can someone please guide me on how to correct this issue?

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "~4.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "websdk-businessobjects": "^3.2.2",
    "websdk-core": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.62.0",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-nuget-pack": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-zip": "^4.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `@angular/animations`, `@angular/cdk`, `@angular/material` that rely on a an 8.x.x version, it should match the other angular packages (v14).